# jQuery ThickBox: Multiple titlebars when calling the initialization method

Tags: jquery, thickbox

I am using jQuery thickBox to make use of the light box effect n my page.Some times i load the content of one of my DIV using jQuery's load method.At that time the thick box didnt worked so I called the initialization function (I put that in another function called PreLoad() and invoiked it  )available in thickbox.js before i load the content to div

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
tb_init('a.thickbox, area.thickbox, input.thickbox');//pass where to apply thickbox
imgLoader = new Image();// preload image
imgLoader.src = tb_pathToImage;
});
```

So thereafter my lightbox worked fine.I wanted to call the PreLoad() function when i load the content again and again.Now if i call the PreLoad function 4 times,I am getting 4 Title bars in my light box. no Idea how to go ahead. Any Thoughts ?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or add

```
$("#TB_window").html("");
```

somewhere at the top of `tb_show` function in the `thickbox.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a call to "tb_remove();" into your interaction pattern.  That should cleanly dismount a thickbox instance.

Just add "tb_remove();" to the top of your PreLoad() function.